# MySQL transactions in InnoDB

Tags: mysql, sql, database, transactions, innodb

I am an MySQL newbie who's learning about transactions, and I'm using the InnoDB engine.

In the MySQL reference manual, I see that they ask to set autocommit to 0 before starting a transaction, but in both ways (setting it to either 0 or 1) I see the same behavior: the transaction is validated after commit and invalidated with Rollback. What is the difference between setting autocommit to 0 or to 1??

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 modes for transactions in InnoDB:

- `autocommit=1` (or `ON`):  Each statement is a transaction.  (See Marc's answer)
- `autocommit=0` (or `OFF`):  You must eventually issue `COMMIT`, else changes will be lost.  (I see this modes a too error-prone to ever use.)
- `BEGIN` (or `START TRANSACTION`) ... `COMMIT` (or `ROLLBACK`):  This explicitly spells out the extent of the transaction.  `autocommit` is ignored.  I consider this to be 'best practice'

Answer (score 1):

If autocommit is on, then every query you issue effectively runs like this:

```
start transaction;
...do a query ...
commit;
start transaction;
... do another query ...
commit
etc...
```

with autocommit off, there's no automatic transaction, and you start it yourself, which makes the code run like this:

```
start transaction
...do a query ...
...do another query ...
... etc...
commit;
```

If you only ever issue single command queries, then there's not much of a difference in behaviors. it's only when you start issuing multiple sequential queries that the new behavior really kicks in.

Comment: i have queries like this :
start transaction
...do a query ...
...do another query ...
... etc...
commit; 
i just want know what is the difference between setting autocommit to 0 or to 1 before starting the transaction.

Answer (score -1):

I think if you use MyISAM storage engine you must set autocommit to 0 but with InnoDB ints not necessary because start transaction sets autocommit to 0 [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2950764/5716786)

Comment: myisam doesn't have transactions, period, so autocommit is ignored

Comment: MyISAM doesn't care about a lot of things, like data integrity, performance, or most of all, transactions.