# Why doesn't MySQL JDBC use "Start transaction" query to start transactions?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jta, jconnect

I have a Java app which uses JTA(Apache Geronimo) to manage transactions. The database in use is MySQL. App has a lot of begin and commit methods. However looking at the MySQL general log I could not find a single "Start transaction" query/command. The log is full of `SET autocommit=1` and `SET autocommit=0` with `commit` and `rollback`. Due to this, looking at logs I am unable to identify at what point the transaction began. I am not a Java guy and I could not find any helping resource on this either.

Comment: because the developers did implement it that way..

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger what could be the reason for not using `start transaction` query/command to initiate a transaction?

Comment: ask the developers, how should I (we) know??? This is not the kind of question for Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks a lot @CarlosHeuberger!

Comment: "set commit = 0" sounds like the beginning of the transaction; commit is clearly the end.  You need to pair those up.

Answer (score 6):

Start transaction and commit statements are used in MySql InnoDB. But In MySQL MyISAM, these commands are not valid so you need to use `set autocommit = 0` instead of Start Transaction and `set autocommit = 1` in place of `commit`;
InnoDB allows both the ways but MyISAM allows only set autocommit. Also, note that these commands perform somewhat similar work but they are not identical. And the use of set autocommit is not recommended in InnoDB.
For more information refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950676/difference-between-set-autocommit-1-and-start-transaction-in-mysql-have-i-misse) in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL's JDBC driver implements the Java JDBC API. The [java.sql.Connection interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) does not have a method to start a transaction.

A transaction begins implicitly when you execute an SQL query.

If the driver is in autocommit mode, the transaction is committed automatically once the SQL query finishes.

If the driver is not in autocommit mode, the transaction started by your query remains active until you call `Connection.commit()` or `Connection.rollback()`.

See also [How to start a transaction in JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940648/how-to-start-a-transaction-in-jdbc)